# Ant: How can I ignore build error if directory doesn't exist?

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant 1.8.1.  How can I ignore the following build error if a directory doesn't exist?  The error I get is

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/davea/myco2-myco/build.xml:211: Directory does not exist: /Users/davea/myco2-myco/${mycousa.test.root}
```

The line in question is the delete directive from the clause below.  Thought the "erroronmissingdir" attribute would have solved the problem, but I guess not …

```
    <delete>
            <fileset dir="${mycousa.test.root}" erroronmissingdir="false">
                    <include name="suite.html" />
            </fileset>
    </delete>
```

Let me know how I can modify the above so that I won't get the error even if the directory doesn't exist.

Thanks - Dave

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the problem is that the error condition you're handling is on the creation of the FileSet, not the delete itself.  Check out the `failonerror` directive on the delete task:

```
<delete failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${mycousa.test.root}" erroronmissingdir="false">
                    <include name="suite.html" />
            </fileset>
</delete>
```

Reference: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html

Comment: Yeah, but if erroronmissingdir is the FileSet should be "missing/empty", and then delete should do nothing (or maybe complain about an empty fileset, but not error with the actual dir path.

Comment: The below answer covers this: there is a bug that was fixed in Ant 1.8.1. So starting with Ant 1.8.1, `erroronmissingdir="false"` works as expected without the need for `failonerror="false"` which also has a negative side-effect of hind _valid_ errors (e.g. user not having write permissions to a file).

Answer (score 7):

It's a bug in ant (version <= 1.8.0).

See

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50124

The fix:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1027000

Comment: This (updating Ant to 1.8.1+) should be the accepted answer: unlike the `<delete failonerror="false">` change suggested above, this solution does not have a side effect of ignoring valid failures (e.g. if directory existed but the user did not have access to remove files from it)