# ant - how to get a zero resource count if the folder does not exist

Tags: ant

I'm trying to base a task on whether a folder has content, not on whether it merely exists. I know there is probably a long winded solution, is there a better solution that I'm missing ?

I've tried two different methods to set a property depending on whether or not a folder has files in it.

My understanding is that 'available' does not permit wildcards like:

```
  <available property="has.test.data" file="${test.data.dir}/**" type="file"/>
```

I tried this but it does not work if the folder (test.data.dir) does not exist:

```
  <fileset id="test.data.files" dir="${test.data.dir}" includes="**/*" />
  <condition property="has.test.data">
    <resourcecount when="greater" count="0"> <fileset refid="test.data.files" /> </resourcecount>
  </condition>
```

Ideally, I want to base a task on whether the folder actually has content, not just an empty folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `erroronmissingdir="false"`, to avoid the error for a non-existing directory. Add `else="false"` if you need the property to always exist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Test resourcecount" xmlns:if="ant:if">

  <fileset id="test.data.files" dir="${test.data.dir}" includes="**/*" erroronmissingdir="false"/>
  <condition property="has.test.data" else="false">
    <resourcecount when="greater" count="0"> <fileset refid="test.data.files" /> </resourcecount>
  </condition>

  <echo if:true="${has.test.data}">${test.data.dir} is exists and is not empty</echo>


</project>
```

related  [Ant: How can I ignore build error if directory doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388775/ant-how-can-i-ignore-build-error-if-directory-doesnt-exist)